# xamarin studio project main class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

it would be great if someone could tell me how to set main class for project in Xamarin Studio?

I try to do this like that:

[xamarin studio build, code generation window for project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPDox.jpg)

Note the grated out triangle, no matter what I write there, nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this particular project has two properties `StartupObject`.

You will have to edit the `.csproj` file and change this to your class:

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <StartupObject>QuantConnect.ToolBox.OandaDownloader.Program</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio are you using? The StartupObject is correctly updated when the Main Class is changed in project options for me. I can create a C# console project and use a different main class when multiple are defined in the project.

Comment: This is project imported from Visual Studio - the [link](https://github.com/QuantConnect/Lean). @MattWard I have no idea why this feature doesn't work as expected, but the fix I did helped me, If you got another answer, I will try it :) Xamarin Studio Community 6.0 (5714).

Comment: I am mostly interested to see if you have found a Xamarin Studio bug :)

Comment: Yeah it seems to work for me using Xamarin Studio 6.0 and changing it in project options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your's project main class (or page). try this:

In the file with the same name as you project is something like this:

`namespace xxxx
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()  //your Application constructor
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(MyMainClass ()); //here you can set your main page
        }
    }
}`